# On what factors does html2pdf generation depends?

Tags: php, html2pdf, xhtml2pdf

I have tried to generate a pdf using html2pdf.
In my localhost, everything works fine. It loads for 3 seconds.
But in my server it takes more than 30 seconds!

I have checked the memory_limit, it says 128M, changed it to 256M (php code), it has the same performance.
Changing libraries isn't an option though, I tried mpdf first but it doesn't support block levels in table. 
Here's my code:

```
include_once APPPATH . 'third_party/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php';
try
{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF($param["orientation"], $param["paper_size"], 'fr');
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont($param["font"]);
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($param["html"], isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $filename = $param["filename"];
    if ($param["action"] == "download") {
        $html2pdf->Output($filename, 'D');
    } else {
        $html2pdf->Output($filename);
    }
} catch (HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
```

Do i need so setup something in my web server?

Comment: Do you implement Images on your production server, which are missing on your localhost? Did you checked, your are loosing time while pdf-creation, or do this happen before calling pdf-function? Check with microtime()! What have you done to find the bottleneck? Did you checked  the debug-output of html2pdf?

Answer (score 0):

you are increasing memory limit but not time limit. As you said its taking 30 seconds or more so you have to increase time limit too.

[heck this link for complete detail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: I've found out that html2pdf library isn't really the right library for me.
The timeout won't help. I've just found out that most html2pdf is easy to use but really slow because of the translation of html to pdf itself.

Comment: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/
this is the good one that I have used already with PHP & command line execution of this code in php